# Python loop just keep going

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a dart score keeper but it just keeps going round and round. I just need some help as to why this is.
The code:

```
import time
import sys
from sys import argv
script, name1, name2 = argv
def dartscore():
    print "Play from 501 or 301?"
    threeorfive = int(raw_input())
    if (threeorfive == 501):
        def playerone():
            startnum1 = threeorfive
            while (startnum1 > 0):
                print "Ready ", name1,"?"
                print "Please enter your score."
                minusnum1 = int(raw_input())
                startnum1 = startnum1 - minusnum1
                playertwo()
            if (startnum1 == 0):
                print "Well done! You win!"
            elif (startnum1 < 0):
                print "Sorry but you have entered a wrong score"
                playertwo()

        def playertwo():
            startnum2 = threeorfive
            print "Ready ", name2,"?"
            print "Please enter your score."
            minusnum2 = int(raw_input())
            startnum2 = startnum2 - minusnum2
            if (startnum2 == 0):
                print "Well done! You win!"
                print "Unlucky ", name1,". Well played though."
                sys.exit()
            if (startnum2 < 0):
                print "Sorry but you have entered an incorrect score. Please try again"
                startnum2 += minusnum2
            playerone()
        playerone()
dartscore()
```

Now the two functions `playerone()` and `playertwo()` are different because I was trying something with the `playerone()` function to see if that solved my problem.

Comment: Sorry for the code not being properly recognised by stack overflow.

Comment: Why are you using recursion? Your local variables don't carry forward to the recursive calls, so the call to `playerone()` from `playertwo()` will set `startnum1` back to `threeorfive` *each time*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the help, so what should i do?

Comment: Not use recursive functions. Use a single loop and call to two functions that return information to the loop to track.

Comment: The project is now fixed for this bug, however i now have another where it calls upon the other player before saying well done to which ever player won

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a `while(startnum1 > 0):`. It seems like `startnum1`is always bigger then 0. The only way to exit your loop is player 2 has a `startnum2` on 0.

Comment: I would but player two has to have the same number at the start as player one, its how a game of darts work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

```
threeorfive = 501
```

Throughout the entire game, and you begin each of your functions with

```
startnum = threeorfive
```

Which means the game 'resets' after both player takes a turn.

A possible fix would be to add global variables:

```
cumulative1 = 0
cumulative2 = 0
```

then update cumulative in each iteration:

```
cumulative1 += minusnum1
cumulative2 += minusnum2
```

and change your while loop to:

```
while(threeorfive - cumulative1 > 0)
while(threeorfive - cumulative2 > 0)
```

Comment: So how would i add a global variable? It isn't something that I have ever done before

Comment: Thanks to @Yeile for helping me solve my original problem